# Can't boot Manjaro from Live USB

Tags: linux, uefi, manjaro, secure-boot, surface

I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04 on Surface Pro 3 and I'm trying to install Manjaro on my machine through a live USB that I've created with this command:

`sudo dd bs=4M if=/path/to/manjaro.iso of=/dev/sd[drive letter] status=progress` (It is from the Manjaro Wiki: https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Burn_an_ISO_File#Writing_to_a_USB_Stick_in_Linux)

This was the ISO file: https://manjaro.github.io/homepage/public/download/kde/

I've disabled Secure Boot and this was the menu I got:

[image]

I selected the first one and then it immediately went to a blank black screen.  Waited a solid 15 minutes and nothing happened.  What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: I did try secure boot enabled and then it gave me "Invalid Signature Detected. Check Secure boot policy in setup".

Comment: If I remember correctly it's possible to modify the Grub settings via something like pressing `e` instead of selecting an OS with `Enter`, try removing the `nosplash` and `quite` options (if present) temporarily; see an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/25024/172838) about such things for more on that subject... What I'll ask is that ya update your question with what comes after enabling a more _verbose_ boot to the Live CD as there's obviously something amiss if it's not booting within a few minuets.